# Placing spaces between links in sidebar-nav bootstrap4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, sidebar

I designed a sidebar with links and am trying to give space between each of the links ive tried adding

```
  .sidebar-nav>li>a{  padding-bottom: 500px; }
```

its not adjusting what alternative can be used to adjust this see full code below...

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2">
       <ul class="navbar sidebar-nav">
         <li class="active"><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
       </ul>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-10"></div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: can you please explain your problem with an image or jsfiddle

Comment: i don't know how to add pictures to comment but what i want is a css to allow me to give distances between each of the links, if i use </br> i'll not be able to add desired spaces between them

Comment: try to increase `col-md-2` to `col-md-8` or something and reduce `col-md-` in the end

Comment: The padding-bottom does not have the desired effect here, because the `a` elements are inline – adding `display:inline-block` (or `block`) would fix this; but then you get that spacing to be part of the link, so it is click-able … if that is not the desired effect, might make more sense to go with margin on the LI to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

don´t know if it's the solution you're looking for, but adding a:

```
</br>
```

before the

```
<li>
```

adds  a space before the next line. try it!

Comment: what i want is a css to allow me to give distances between each of the links, if i use </br> i'll not be able to add desired spaces between them